# Sender and Server UDP problems

Tags: java, udp, client, server-side

I have a problem with a Sender and a Server UDP. The `SenderUDP` sends an object and the `ServerUDP` must receive it. For the first object all works fine, but when I try to send another object the server throws a `StreamCorruptedException`.
Here the client side code:

```
public class SenderUDP implements Runnable {
private java.net.DatagramSocket clientsocket;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private int port;
private InetAddress ip;
private Packet objToSend;
private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;


public SenderUDP(String ip, int port, Packet p) throws UnknownHostException{
    this.ip =InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    this.port = port;
    this.objToSend = p;
    this.out = null;
    this.clientsocket = null;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        clientsocket = new DatagramSocket ();
        System.out.println("Inside senderUDP");
        byte[] sendData;                    
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        out.writeObject(objToSend);
        sendData = baos.toByteArray();           
        DatagramPacket sendpacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length,ip,port);            
        clientsocket.send(sendpacket);                 
        System.out.println("Sended packet with UDP");
        out.flush();
        if(this.objToSend.getOP() == 1){
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];                
            int read;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int)this.objToSend.getFile().length());                
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(objToSend.getFile());
            while((read = fis.read(buf)) != -1){
                bas.write(buf, 0, read);
            }
            DatagramPacket sendfile = new DatagramPacket(bas.toByteArray(), bas.toByteArray().length, ip, port);
            clientsocket.send(sendfile);
        }           
        out.close();             
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException uhe) {
        System.err.println(uhe.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Here is the server side code:

```
class ServerUDP implements Runnable {
private DatagramSocket socket;
private int port;
private Controller controller;
private byte[] buffer;
private DatagramPacket packet;
private Packet p;
private ObjectInputStream ois;

public ServerUDP(int port, Controller controller){
    this.socket = null;
    this.port = port;
    this.controller = controller;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerUDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    while(true){               
        buffer = new byte[1000000];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
        System.out.println("Ascolto UDP!");
        try {                
            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println(packet);
            System.out.println("1");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerUDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Packet UDP Received!");
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerUDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            p = (Packet) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Pacchetto/Evento arrivato con UDP!");
            System.out.println(p);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerUDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if(p.getOP() == 1){
            Thread t = new Thread(new FilesManager(socket,p,false, controller));
            t.start();
        }
        controller.enqueue(p);
        try {
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerUDP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The `StreamCorruptedException` is thrown by

```
ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
```

and

```
p = (Packet) ois.readObject();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not use TCP for streaming the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, you totally forgot to implement a protocol! You forgot to do transmit pacing, duplicate datagram detection, checksums, datagram reordering, retransmissions, acknowledgements, slow start, sliding windows, and pretty much everything else! You may not absolutely need all of these things, but you need most of them or you need to accomplish these basic functions some other way.

You've done about 1% of the job of sending data using UDP. It won't work until you finish the job.

If you want minimal file transfer over UDP, then TFTP is what you want to study. Here's a description of how a file transfer occurs over UDP:

> The initiating host A sends an RRQ (read request) or WRQ (write request) packet to host S at the well-known port number 69, containing the filename and transfer mode.
>
> S replies with an ACK (acknowledgement) packet to WRQ and directly with a DATA packet to RRQ. Packet is sent from a freshly allocated ephemeral port, and all future packets to host S should be to this port.
>
> The source host sends numbered DATA packets to the destination host, all but the last containing a full-sized block of data (512 bytes). The destination host replies with numbered ACK packets for all DATA packets.
>
> The final DATA packet must contain less than a full-sized block of data to signal that it is the last. If the size of the transferred file is an exact multiple of the block-size, the source sends a final DATA packet containing 0 bytes of data.
>
> Receiver responds to each DATA with associated numbered ACK. Sender responds to the first received ACK of a block with DATA of the next block.
>
> If an ACK is not eventually received, a retransmit timer resends DATA packet.
>
> [Trivial File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) - Wikipedia

This avoids the need to do transmit pacing, slow start, windows, or datagram reordering by only keeping one chunk of data "in flight" at a time. That makes it very slow, but also pretty simple. As described above, you can at best exchange 512 bytes per round trip time.

Comment: Hi! First thanks for answer! I've forgot to say that i sending only one segment using UDP. The main of the client checks the size of the file, and if it's less of 60k it send in UDP. Else it send in TCP. So i think that i don't need checksum etc, because i send always only one packet UDP.

Comment: You are confusing packets with datagrams. You can't send a 60K packet (unless this is a private intranet that's all GigE with jumbo frames). It will take about 40 packets to carry a datagram that large. And if even one packet of the datagram is lost, the datagram is lost. For example, if packet loss is .5%, datagram loss will be 87%! That is, your datagram will get through one out of eight times. So at a minimum, you'll need acknowledgements and retransmissions.

Comment: Ok maybe i've express the concept badly.In my application a packet is an object that contains 2 Strings, 1 int, 1 File. I need to send this object. I check the size of File.If this size is <60k i want to send the object using UDP. And here all works fine. In the object the int is called opearation (op).If operation is 1 i want to send the File. Using UDP ofc.So in the SenderUDP class i open a FileInputStream and i read the file trying to send it. In the server side i want to receive the object, and after received i want to check the operation(op).If it is 1 i want to receive the file. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so you need to write a protocol. It doesn't seem that you've done that. If you send it as one big datagram, you need to do retransmission and acknowledgement. If not, you need to do duplicate datagram detection, transmit pacing, and so on. (You might want to read the TCP specification. Everything TCP does that you need, you have to do if you want to use UDP.)

Comment: Ok understood! Thanks for your answer! There are some tutorial for implementing protocol? I really have no idea about it!

Comment: I would strongly urge you to just use TCP unless you have a good reason not to (and then, the best way to do it depends on why you're using UDP). I wouldn't recommend touching UDP until you've mastered TCP. (And if you have, start out by making a specification for your protocol. You can use the TCP protocol specification as a guide.)

Comment: I have to use UDP. I am a student of Computer Science Engineering, and i need to implement a project for a course of software engineering. It's not my choose, really i rather use TCP!

Comment: Then my advice to you would be to study [TFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) in as much detail as possible. It's file transfer over UDP. (see updates)

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, you may want to tag these questions `homework`. Even though this isn't exactly homework, that would let people know that your requirements aren't flexible and that your solution doesn't have to be quite as real world.

Comment: OK, in the future i will do it!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question why the StreamCorruptedException occurs.

Comment: It does. The [StreamCorruptedException](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/StreamCorruptedException.shtml) occurs because the data is mangled due to the failure to implement a protocol that preserves the integrity of the data. But it's totally pointless to try to debug code when the "bug" is that it fails when it tries to do something that it is completely missing most of the logic necessary to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a new ObjectInputStream each time you have a new ObjectOutputStream at the other end, and at no other time. In this case you are using UDP where datagrams are independent, so you need a new OIS each packet, so you need a new OOS each packet too.

As David Schwartz points out, you +also+ need to consider what happens if packets don't arrive, or arrive twice, or out of order, but the solution to your immediate problem is a new OOS per packet.